# Command not found when running defined function in script file

Tags: bash, shell

I have defined a function in bash_profile file.

```
pse(){
ps -ef|grep $1
}
```

Now i can call this function from command line. Like

```
pse kafka
```

It is working fine as i can see the correct output.
But when i am trying to call pse function in an script file, it is showing me "command not found" error. Am i missing something? Are we not allowed to call function defined in bash_profile from shell script? 
OS : MacOsX Yosemite

Comment: Did you source your `bash_profile` after adding the function into the file? `source ~/.bash_profile` probably.

Comment: yeah i did that, that's why i can call that function from command line and it is showing correct output

Comment: You have the `source` command **in the script**?

Comment: You don't want this function anyway. You want `pgrep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`export`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) the function from the parent's shell to make it available in the child processes:

```
export -f pse
```

From the manual:

> export
>
> ```
> export [-fn] [-p] [name[=value]]
> ```
>
> Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment. If the -f option is supplied, the names refer to shell functions;
>   otherwise the names refer to shell variables. The -n option means to
>   no longer mark each name for export. If no names are supplied, or if
>   the -p option is given, a list of names of all exported variables is
>   displayed. The -p option displays output in a form that may be reused
>   as input. If a variable name is followed by =value, the value of the
>   variable is set to value.
>
> The return status is zero unless an invalid option is supplied, one of the names is not a valid shell variable name, or -f is supplied
>   with a name that is not a shell function.

Comment: Yeah now it is working. But why ? Isn't doing source ~/.bash_profile is an equivalent operation.

Comment: `source` "includes" (runs) the function only in the current shell. `export` makes it available in all child processes. So you need both here. Or you can directly `source` it in your script.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only sourced by interactive shells; scripts are executed by non-interactive shells.

Comment: @P.P. how would you source it inside the script? I tried doing this with my function using `source functionName` but when running the script it errors

Comment: @GrayedFox `source` takes a filename. So, if you defined `functionName` in `my_utils.sh` then you can do: `source my_utils.sh`.

Comment: So I literally source the script file from inside the script itself... i.e. `source ./scriptName.sh`

Comment: @GrayedFox Not from the *same* script (if the function is defined in the same script, you wouldn't need to source it at all).